# Spring & JPA: Create database schema and tables on demand

Tags: java, spring, jpa, schema

Is there any possibility in JPA/Spring to create/delete a database schema with a custom name and according tables (given by @Entity annotations) at runtime, e.g. when the user presses a button?

I only know about the `javax.persistence.schema-generation` properties, which are executed at startup of my application and use a predefined schema name.

A short (and simplified) example of what I am looking for:

Let's say I have two entities, `Dog` and `Cat`. When the user presses a button, a new schema `animals1` with two tables `Dog` and `Cat` is created. All queries now go to schema `animals1`. When the user presses the button a second time, a different schema `animals2` with the two tables is created, and all queries now go to `animals2`.

I assume there is some magic I can do in Spring, but I have no clue where to start. I would be grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

There is an API for "generateSchema" in JPA:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html#generateSchema-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-

Check this blog entry
https://antoniogoncalves.org/2014/12/11/generating-database-schemas-with-jpa-2-1/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How would I dynamically define the name of the schema with this API? If I use an arbitrary persistenceUnit name, I get the following: `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No persistence provider found for schema generation for persistence-unit named animals1PersistenceUnit`