# How to Spring Boot + Data JPA generate schema (eg. table, field, column) in controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I don't want to generate schema when application is running.

I would like when the controller was called by user and then generate schema.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring & JPA: Create database schema and tables on demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39288383/spring-jpa-create-database-schema-and-tables-on-demand)

Comment: The linked question goes beyond your question but answers tell you how to programmatically run schema generation whenever you want.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @Jens Schauder
I found solution on you recommended

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="sample" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.mydomain.User</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="create"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target" value="create.ddl"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="metadata"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="import.sql"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app_restaurant_1?useSSL=false"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

create persistence.xml and put on main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

```
@GetMapping("/category")
private List<Category> getCategory(){
    Persistence.generateSchema("sample", null); // -- generate schema in persistence.xml
    return categoryService.getCategory();
}
```

on the controller, When controller is called generate schema in @Entity